# Add Limit Lines to D3.js Line Graph

Tags: d3.js

Is there a way of adding limit lines to a D3.js line graph as per image below? (doesn't have to be dashed) I have upper and lower limit columns in my database.  Have been searching unsuccessfully online for an example of how this could be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Not sure exactly what a 'limit line' is, but this is visually not a problem. As a starting point, I'd suggest this:

```
// (assuming some vars have been created per usual templates)

svg.append( "line" )
  .attr("x1", x( x.domain()[0] ) )
  .attr("x2", x( x.domain()[1] ) )
  .attr("y1", y( 80 ) )   // whatever the y-val should be
  .attr("y2", y( 80 ) )
```

Then add css or attrs to define your line's specific look.

Please comment on any ways in which it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thank you - I'll try that and let you know how it goes:)

Answer (score 0):

I did work around by introducing another set of lines having constant y-values,
resulting in this chart:
[image]
It's basically a multi line chart with additional two lines as shown [here](https://next.plnkr.co/plunk/8aj8ZU).