# Add Limit Lines to D3.js Line Graph

Tags: d3.js

Hi. Is there a way to put a limit line for a d3js line graph? means a limit line along x axis which shows the maximum limit!

```
svg.append( "line" )
.attr("x1", x( x.domain()[0] ) )
.attr("y1", y( 80 ) )   // whatever the y-val should be
```

This is the code I have used rightnow.but not working.having doubt with the css part

Can anyone please give me a detailed overview?

Comment: Please provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to work with

Comment: To create a line you have  to define two points.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15116933/add-limit-lines-to-d3-js-line-graph             this is something similar to what i need.but not really working.Sorry i am unable to upload an image  and thanks  Imperative and  Anto Jurković for your response.Special thanks to Neeku

Comment: What is it, that is "not working"? Please provide more code and a detailed error message. The sample you got from the other SO question is pretty solid and straightforward. Just Create a new line, which must have two coordinates (`start: x1, y1` and `end: x2,y2`).

Comment: Another similar question [Add a line on the y axis d3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24014391/add-a-line-on-the-y-axis-d3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the answer for my question.Hope this will help someone in the future.Thanks a a lot to all who have responded to my query.

```
.line {
stroke: #993300;
fill: none;
stroke-width: 0.75px;
}

.line.line5 {
 stroke:red; 
}


var valueline2 = d3.svg.line()

.x(function(d) { return main_x(d.date); })

.y(function(d) { return main_y0(Value); });

 var main1 = svg.append("g")

.attr("transform", "translate(" + main_margin.left + "," + main_margin.top + ")"); 


 main1.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")
    .attr("class", "line line5")
    .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
    .attr("d", valueline2);

    main1.append("text")      
        .attr("x", 890)
        .attr("y",  65 )
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Value");
```